# useEffect is not getting called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

Please anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

while working, I got stuck on a problem. My `useEffect` is not getting called. I have changed dependencies several times, but in vain.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Card, Col, Image, ListGroup, Row } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import Loader from '../components/Loader'
import Message from '../components/Message'
import { getOrderDetails } from '../redux/actions/orderActions'

function OrderPage() {

    const { id } = useParams()
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const orderDetails = useSelector(state => state.orderDetails)
    const { order, error, loading } = orderDetails

    debugger
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!order || order._id !== Number(id)) {
            dispatch(getOrderDetails(id))
        }
    }, [order, dispatch, id, orderDetails])
    
    if (!loading && !error) {
       order.itemsPrice = order.orderItems.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.price * item.qty, 0).toFixed(2)
   }
```

Here, my `useEffect` is not triggering first, rather it goes to check inside `if` condition and throwing error. It seems peculiar to me as I have put condition `!loading` & `!error`. It should not check inside `if` until I get `order` from `redux store`.

Please someone help me. Thanks again.

Comment: try console the values of `order` see result

Comment: as far as I understand you'd need to get the order detaits the there is an order, so `if (order || order._id !== Number(id))` instead of `if (!order || order._id !== Number(id))`

Comment: @NarendraJadhav It is ```undefined```

Comment: @rustyBucketBay I'll get it from backend. So initially ```order``` is empty.

Comment: `if` is getting checked because loading and error both are undefined initially and the reverse of that is true that's my guess

Comment: @vatsalsoni ```if``` block should be called after ```useeffect```. While my ```loading``` & ```error``` is coming from ```redux store```, they will be populated after ```useEffect``` being triggered.

Comment: how about add `order.itemsPrice = order.orderItems.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.price * item.qty, 0).toFixed(2)` below the dispatch inside useEffect?
and remove the the If condition

Comment: @vatsalsoni If I can  populate ```order```, it will give those which are coming from my state.

Comment: Hello brothers.... No solution?

Answer (score 0):

useEffect will always run the first time after the first render and then the other time it will run if any of the dependencies get changed

So you would need to have the below code for useEffect

```
    useEffect(() => {
    if (!order) {
        dispatch(getOrderDetails(id))
    } else if ( order._id !== Number(id) ) {
       dispatch(getOrderDetails(id))
    }
}, [order, dispatch, id, orderDetails])
```

This will check if the order is not there then get the order, or if the order is there but the order id does match with the id we get from the URL then also fetch the order.

Comment: Yes, ```useEffect``` should be triggered at first render. But it is not being triggered at first render. I have checked several way. Many thanks for your reply but still it's not working.